# GE. Have sound continue on different scenes

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm trying to do the following.
When I click on the cube object it goes to the 002 scene.
But when I tighten the cube in the scene 002 there are two songs to can...
I used the 'Add Overlay Scene' so the song continues to run between scenes.

[image: Camera + Music]

[image: Scene.001]

[image: Scene.002]

Comment: Please please please next time 
explain better, 
It seems that you grabbed some words from your brain and vomited them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the sound actuator dont persist between scenes so you need to use [AUD Basic Sound Playback](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/aud.html) in order to persist between scenes.

To make it persisten save the handle in an attribute of module bge.logic as shown in the example [TEXTURE Basic Video Playback](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.texture.html?highlight=texture#module-bge.texture)

This python script will try to play the sound when enter to scene "Scene" if not already playing (will play until end and is needed to load scene "Scene" in order to play again)

```
"""https://docs.blender.org/api/current/aud.html"""
import aud
from bge import logic

# the creation of the handle must be done once per sound: save the
# handle in an attribute of bge.logic module makes it persistent
if not hasattr(logic,'handle'):

    device = aud.device()
    # load sound file (it can be a video file with audio)
    factory = aud.Factory(logic.expandPath('//spring moon.mp3'))

    # play the audio, this return a handle to control play/pause
    logic.handle = device.play(factory)

if logic.handle.status:
    print('playing sound', logic.handle.status)
else:
    delattr(logic, 'handle')
```

[image]

Also you can use that logic in all cameras so when set any scene will try to play if not already playing.

Finally you can change the scene actuators to jus set scene:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The non-coding solution is to have a central, main scene that plays the sound.

That way the main scene will still persist, even when other scenes are being changed/removed.